# An algebraic foliation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ with real coefficients whose all complex limit cycles intersect the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations, limit-cycles

Is there a polynomial vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that every complex limit cycle
of the corresponding foliation of $\mathbb{C}^2$  must necessarily intersect the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Remark 1: We exclude the case that there is no any comlex limit cycle at all. So to avoid triviality we assume that we have at least one complex limit cycle.  Namely we assume that there exist at least one non singular leaf with non trivial holonomy group.

Remark 2: The motivation for this question is introduced here:

https://maco.lu.ac.ir/article-1-86-en.html